# Error of Connection already released while connecting backend with frontend

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I connected my express backend with react frontend using axios.However i am getting an error of `connection already released`.I think there is due to the poor connection with backend.Hoping for help.

My express backend `index.js` has following code

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var cors = require('cors')

const mySql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT||5000

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Database
const pool = mySql.createPool({
connectionLimit:100,
host:'localhost',
user:'root',
password:'',
database:'nodejsauthentication'
 })
 //Creating New Accounts
function createUser(req,res){
 if(req.body.Password === req.body.ConfirmPassword){
 pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{
 if (err) throw err
 connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}'`,(errors,result)=>{
 connection.release();
 if(errors) {throw errors}
         
 if(result =="")
   {
    var sql = `INSERT INTO USERS (name,email,password) VALUES('${req.body.Name}','${req.body.Email}','${req.body.Password}')`
     connection.query(sql,(Err,response)=>{
     connection.release
     if(Err) throw Err
     res.send("Sucessfully created Account.LogIn to continue");
       })
      }
     else
      {
       res.send("Email is Already Taken");
       } 
     })
  })
}
else
{
 res.send("Passwords Don't Match.Try Again");
}    
 }
  //MiddleWare for logging In.
 function authenticate(req,res)
{
  pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{
   if(err) throw err
    
   connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}'`,(err,result)=>{
   connection.release();

   if(err) throw err
   if(result == "")
   res.send("No user is associated with that email");
   else{
      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}' AND password='${req.body.Password}'`,(err,result)=>{
       connection.release();
    
     if(err) throw err
      else{
       if(result == "")
        {
          res.send("Email or password Didnot Match");
         }
         else{
           res.send("Congratulations!!!")
            }
          }
       })
     }
   })      
 })
}
//requests
 app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send("At '/'");
  })

app.post('/home',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
  console.log("Recieved a post request");
  })

app.post('/createUser',createUser,(req,res)=>{
console.log("creating new Users");
 })

//listen to a server
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log(`Server running sucessfully at port ${PORT}`)
 })
```

Here is what I have written in my frontend

```
import {React,Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './form.css';

export default class signIn extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  Name:'',
  Email:'',
  Password:'',
  ConfirmPassword:'',
  Response:''
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleClick(e){
this.setState({
 [e.target.name]:e.target.value
})
}
handleSubmit(e){
console.log("Submitted");
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/createUser',{
Name:this.state.Name,
Email:this.state.Email,
Password:this.state.Password,
ConfirmPassword:this.state.ConfirmPassword
}).then((res)=>{
this.setState({
 Name:'',
 Email:'',
 Password:'',
 ConfirmPassword:'',
 Response:res.data
 })
})
}
render(){
return (
<div>
<h5 className="message">{this.state.Response}</h5>
<div className="contact">
<section className="cntct">
<form >
<input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Name} required/>
<input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Email} required/>
<input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.Password} required/>
<input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.ConfirmPassword} required/>
<button type="button"className="logIn" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Create Account</button>
</form>
</section>
</div>
</div>
 )
 }
}
```

In my debugging console I have these following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

Comment: send postman request to check API working or not if working then the problem is with frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are releasing the SQL connection at line 5 of **createUser** before you do the insert

```
function createUser(req,res){
 if(req.body.Password === req.body.ConfirmPassword){
 pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{
 if (err) throw err
 connection.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='${req.body.Email}'`,(errors,result)=>{
// connection.release();
 if(errors) {throw errors}
         
 if(result =="")
   {
    var sql = `INSERT INTO USERS (name,email,password) VALUES('${req.body.Name}','${req.body.Email}','${req.body.Password}')`
     connection.query(sql,(Err,response)=>{
     connection.release
     if(Err) throw Err
     res.send("Sucessfully created Account.LogIn to continue");
       })
      }
     else
      {
       res.send("Email is Already Taken");
       } 
     })
  })
}
else
```

Also Add a catch to the promise to get a reason of the error.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/createUser',{
Name:this.state.Name,
Email:this.state.Email,
Password:this.state.Password,
ConfirmPassword:this.state.ConfirmPassword
}).then((res)=>{
this.setState({
 Name:'',
 Email:'',
 Password:'',
 ConfirmPassword:'',
 Response:res.data
 })
})
.catch(err => {
  // log the error
})
```